# display actual xml with nodes as html but browser friendly

Tags: html, xml, ajax, xslt, stylesheet

I want to display my XML ajax response in html for the browser. However what I need is the actual xml itself being displayed i.e. the full tree with the elements AND the content not just the content of the nodes.

So I want the xml to be displayed as the browser e.g.:

```
<element>content</element>
    <element2>niijojoi</element2>
    <element2>niijojoi</element2>
    <element2>niijojoi</element2>
 //etc more nested elements some with atrributes etc
```

I have a stylesheet that would display the text but does anyone have an xsl stylesheet that simply traverses the xml and outputs it to the browser as is with indentation etc.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your XML via Ajax - simply put the result in a `textarea` and then style the textarea any way you want.

```css
textarea {
  background: #eee;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
  
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get your XML via AJAX and want to inject it into an element on the page (a `<pre>` element would make sense), all you have to do is to replace `<` characters with the `&lt;` entity before injecting the content into the `innerHTML` of the `<pre>` element:

```
// "result" is the data from the AJAX request.
$('#xml').innerHTML = result.replace('<', '&lt;');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is automatically performed by a browser. For instance, if I create a file test.xml and put this in it:

```
<a>
  <element>content</element>
  <element1>
    <element2>niijojoi</element2>
    <element2>niijojoi</element2>
    <element2>niijojoi</element2>
  </element1>
</a>
```

and open it in Google Chrome, it shows the XML hierarchy with indentation.

Comment: yes you are right. But this only works if as you say, we open the file in a browser. What I need is for the XML to be displayed as part of the web page itself, in other words like a fragment of text alongside other web html content. The browser in this case cannot render the xml as it gets confused and doesnt know what to do with the tags. This applies to all browsers.